# Babel doesn't seem to translate JSX?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm following the tutorial on frontendmasters.com and tried to simplify one of the setups there. I see the following error when I type `yarn build`, which I assume is because babel didn't get rid of the JSX prior to running webpack:

```
ERROR in ./js/ClientApp.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:25)

  3 | import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
  4 | 
> 5 | const HelloWorld = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
    |                          ^
  6 | 
  7 | const App = () => (
  8 |   <BrowserRouter>
```

My `package.json` for the yarn build is:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --list-different --single-quote --print-width=120 webpack.config.js \"js/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "build:dev": "webpack -d"
  },
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "eslint": "^4.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flow": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.44.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.6.1",
    "prettier": "^1.10.2"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js is:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./js/ClientApp.jsx",
  devtool: "cheap-eval-source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: 'babel-loader',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My `js/ClientApp.jsx` is just a simple syntactically valid file, which I'm leaving out, since StackOverflow is already complaining that this message is mostly code.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong and why babel isn't correctly handling the JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Babel is yet not configured to transpile your code properly.

Given you're using an `es2015` + `React JSX` syntax, the quick way would consist of installing Babel's [ES2015 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) and [React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) as dev dependencies and configure your `.babelrc` file to use them:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

If you wanted to fine tune your babel setup, you might consider installing only the Babel **plugins** you actually need instead of the mentioned **presets** (which are just a set of Babel plugins),

Comment: Yeah, seems like I also needed a .babelrc file. Now everything works as expected.